# launchctl can't run the binary and exits with a code 78

Tags: macos, plist, root, daemon, launchctl

I've been building a golang [app](https://gist.github.com/krlc/8b9a79b33b857d1a66221ffc802d3c0d) with system tray GUI. I wanted `launchctl` to run my program whenever I log in. Program compiles and runs without any error, however, when `launchctl` runs it, I see this: `Service exited with abnormal code: 78`. Perhaps it has something to do with rights.

- First I tried to set rights of a current user to both `plist` file and the binary. Still error `78`.
- Then I changed the rights of `plist` file and the binary to **root** and run `sudo launchctl`. I still see error `78`.

`/var/log/system.log` has this errors:

```
14:46:00 Macchiato com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.test.test[519]): Service could not initialize: 18A391: xpcproxy + 11291 [1534][8188841E-6D08-3F80-8488-9B5D7462BACB]: 0xd
14:46:00 Macchiato com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.test.test[519]): Service exited with abnormal code: 78
14:46:00 Macchiato com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.test.test): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

The `plist` file itself is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.test.test</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/Users/test-user/test/test</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>ProcessType</key>
        <string>Standard</string>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/var/log/test-err.log</string>
        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/var/log/test-out.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Error logs are empty.

When I run the [binary](https://gist.github.com/krlc/8b9a79b33b857d1a66221ffc802d3c0d) manually, the icon of the app appears on the system tray, as expected.

*There's one interesting moment* – if I manually type `launchctl load -w com.test.test.plist`, app runs nicely – until the reboot. After I reboot, `launchctl` throws `78` error.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

I think I solved my own question. It seems the error `78` comes when I use

```xml
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/var/log/test-err.log</string>
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/var/log/test-out.log</string>
```

When I removed this lines, the error disappeared. This is especially odd, because the `plist` file has root permissions and `launchd` runs as root either...

Comment: I think you're confused about the distinction between launch agents (which run as regular users inside user sessions) and launch daemons (which mostly run as root, independent of who's logged in). If you want this to run in a user session, it *must* be an agent, in which case it will not have permissions to write to /var/log.

Comment: When you remove the paths above, does the log and error output end up elsewhere or nowhere?

Comment: This has no effect for me. Notably I'm also using a go program and built in functions (sleep) work.

Answer (score 1):

Error 78 means that there is no permission to write to the log files you have specified.

to resolve this error, change the owner or the permissions of the log files.